# My Activity is getting slow as i am fetching images from other activity

Tags: android, file, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

My Activity is getting slow as i am fetching images from other activity
what should i do to make the activity fast should i reduce the image size .
Please help me to get out it and tell me what should i used in of shared preference for fetching images from other activity.
Thanks
here is code

```
            title=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    description=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    phonenumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    price=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
    postadd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_post);

    location=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    category=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
    subcategory=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcategory);



    imageview1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    imageview2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    imageview3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    imageview4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);



    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    locationname = preferences.getString("Location", "Location");

    SharedPreferences preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    categoryname = preferences1.getString("categoryname", "categoryname");

    SharedPreferences imagepath1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath1 = imagepath1.getString("picturePath1", "picturePath1");


    SharedPreferences imagepath2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath2 = imagepath2.getString("picturePath2", "picturePath2");

    SharedPreferences imagepath3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath3 = imagepath3.getString("picturePath3", "picturePath3");

    SharedPreferences imagepath4 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    selectedImagePath4 = imagepath4.getString("picturePath4", "picturePath4");



     AQuery aq = new AQuery(PostAddActivity.this);

     String imageUrl1 = selectedImagePath1;            
     aq.id(imageview1).image(imageUrl1);

     String imageUrl2 = selectedImagePath2;            
     aq.id(imageview2).image(imageUrl2);

     String imageUrl3 = selectedImagePath3;            
     aq.id(imageview3).image(imageUrl3);

     String imageUrl4 = selectedImagePath4;            
     aq.id(imageview4).image(imageUrl4);



    location.setText(locationname);
    category.setText(categoryname);
    subcategory.setText(subcategoryname);
    subcategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    postadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {                       

            final String email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
            final String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";


            if(title.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(PostAddActivity.this, "Fill your name !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(description.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(PostAddActivity.this, "Fill the Description !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (!email1.matches(emailPattern))
            { 
                Toast.makeText(PostAddActivity.this, "Email id is invalid !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            new GetData().execute();


        }
        });

}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
           String Title = title.getText().toString();
           String Description = description.getText().toString().trim();
           String PhoneNumber = phonenumber.getText().toString();
           String Email = email.getText().toString();
           String Price = price.getText().toString();
        try
           {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://tradewale.com/open/tradedata.php?home_cat=1");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(result);

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
             value = obj.getString("Success");

                }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            }

        return value;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
         int val=Integer.parseInt(value);
         if (val==1)
         {
            Toast.makeText(PostAddActivity.this, "Thank you For Inquiry ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
         }

         else
         {
             Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostAddActivity.class);

                 startActivity(in);
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i see you used aquery... just use this option:

```
aq.id(imageview1).image(imageUrl, true, true, 200, 0); //200px width
```

Comment: need to ask one for thing simas are  you there

Comment: are on fb or give id so that i can talk u easily

Comment: how can i send images to server through json

Comment: this is a complete different question.first you have to give a try by yourself, then if you have a problem you can post another question.